# Changing css selector for parent template using twig

Tags: html, css, twig

I can't just figure out how to handle different css selectors in different templates.

For example I have base template as follows

```
    <div id="main" class="container">
        <div id="content" class="content section row">
            <div class="col-md-8 bg-base col-lg-8 col-xl-9"> 
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div><!--/col-md-8 bg-base col-lg-8 col-xl-9-->

            <div class="sidebar col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
                {% block sidebar %}

                {% endblock %}
            </div>

        </div>

    </div><!--#main.container-->
```

For example in user-login.html I want to change `<div id="content" class="content section row">` content section row to something else

Same with columns. for example in a page that I don't have a sidebar I want to change `<div class="col-md-8 bg-base col-lg-8 col-xl-9">` col-lg-8 to col-lg-12

How can I do this dynamical? How do you guys handle these kind of inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

With the power of template inheritance you can do all that.

**Example1:**

Use a block for the `div#content` class attribute:

*base.html*

```
<div id="main" class="container">
    <div id="content" class="{% block contentClass %}content section row{% endblock %}">
        <div class="col-md-8 bg-base col-lg-8 col-xl-9"> 
            {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*sub-template.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block contentClass %}content whatever{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  some content
{% endblock %}
```

**Example2:**

If you have different layouts, e.g. a fullwidth and a sidebar layout, I would suggest to create a subtemplate for each layout, and then extend the layout you need:

*base.html*

```
<div id="main" class="container">
    <div id="content" class="content section row">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
```

*fullwidth.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

*sidebar.html*

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col-md-8 bg-base col-lg-8 col-xl-9">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
        {% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Instead of extending `base.html`, you can now extend `fullwidth.html` or `sidebar.html` in your page-templates, e.g:

*login.html*

```
{% extends "fullwidth.html" %}
{% block content %}
    ... login form ...
{% endblock %}
```

*about.html*

```
{% extends "sidebar.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>About</h1>
    <p>bla bla</p>
{% endblock %}
{% block sidebar %}
    <h2>besides</h2>
    <p>bla bla</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is actually a good answer which is applicable. But you can't use `{% block content %}` inside `{% block content %}`. Throws an error `A template that extends another one cannot include content outside Twig blocks.`. Call the second, inner one `{% block layout_content %}`.